# Memory problems, while using UIMA Ruta

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, uima, ruta

**The problem:**

I'm using UIMA Ruta (v2.3.1) in one of my projects, but now I'm facing a problem:
The memory exceeds explainable sizes, but it can't be figured out, where this problem is located, except for the class **org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RuleElementMatch**, that takes up to 50% of memory usage.

I call the JavaAPI of UIMA Ruta in my project, to set up the analysis engine. When I'm sending a text to analyze with around 400kbyte size to this engine, there are around 700MB memory blocked by this process, but without any chance for the GC to free some space.

**Ruta project:**

The given Ruta rules are built-up with REGEXP-structures, but theoretical they should reduce the amount of memory usage, because there are UNMARKALL-Statements at specific endpoints.

Is someone facing the same situation of high memory consumption or are there any suggested solutions? Using the low memory profile as an advice of uima itself is not possible, due the response time is already at around 30 seconds. Increasing the max memory of the JVM is not an option.

Comment: Which part of the Java API do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by REGEXP-structures? REGEXP condition or simple regex rules? At what kind of rules are the UNAMRKALL actions? What do you mean by endpoint?

Comment: How should I understand the question for the JavaAPI? We're building an AnalysisEngine as described in the documentation for this API, adding all typesystems needed and push a text to analyze against this engine with the process-method.

The REGEX-Structures are in the conditional part of our composed rule just like the following example:

**(ANY{REGEXP("(H|h)ello")} ANY{REGEXP("(Mr.|Mrs.)")}){ NOT(IS(Greetings)) ->MARK(Greetings)}**

Comment: We have six of them in a row for different linguistic examples we want to check against, after all, there is an UNMARKALL like ->UNMARKALL(Annotation, {Greetings})

where we normally expect to reduce the amount of annotations still in memory, but that didn't fix the problem.

We have this big text with 400Kbyte, that would be analyzed with an load average of 700MB memory, if we take a part of this text, we expected to reduce this load, bit crashs our JVM, because the memory fills up with this suspicious RuleElementMatch class.

Comment: We were bugfixing some time and found some ruta statements, that we're some memory suspects. An improvement can be seen, but the memory is still leaking. As we figured out, there is an issue at RutaBasic class, that there are some arrays reserved, that are only filled with some single elements. The main part is still empty at runtime.

We've created an issue at your Jira, UIMA-5306 for this case

Comment: Thanks for the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not an answer, but here are some comments that maybe help.

As the name says, RutaRuleElementMatch stores the matches of rule elements, which is required wihtin one RuleMatch in order to identify the information for the actions. This information can be forgotten after a RuleMatch, but sometimes it is necessary to store it. Mainly, it is stored if the analysis engine is configured for debugging (parameters `debug` and `debugWithMacthes`). Then, all rule matches and rule element matches are remembered in order to create the debug annotations later. If there are many matches, this can take a lot of memory in the current implementation.

The debug config is also used in the Java API, e.g., in Ruta.select() or Ruta.matches(). In a smaller amount, the matches are also remembered for the head rules of block statements.

So, if debugging is activated, it should be deactivated in order to reduce the memory usage.

400KB of text is quite a lot, I think. Ruta brings quite some overhead, which is required, but can also be improved/reduced. Right now, until the implementation is improved, there are some best practices in order to handle large document in ruta, i.e. reduce the memory usage.

In your use case, I would switch to a different seeder which creates only annotations you need, and only where you need them, e.g., do you need SPACE and BREAK? Then, I would refactor the rules. The example rule you mentioned in the comments is extremely inefficient, and produces many RuleElementMatches. I rather recommend to use dictionary lookup where possible, e.g. with `TRIE`. You can also improve such rule by restricting the match condition. In your example, this could be `W` or the output of some dictionary lookup.

If profiling shows that a lot of memory is used by RutaRuleElementMatch, then this can be caused by the debug config, or by inefficient rules.

If profiling shows that a lot of memory is used by RutaBasic, then it is caused by the size of the document and therefore by the amount of annotations. Reducing the amount of annotations helps, as less coverage information needs to be stored in the internal lists/arrays. `UNMARK` and `UNMARKALL` help also but not to an extend one expects, at least in my use cases. There is also the parameter `lowMemoryProfile` which reduces the memory usage of RutaBasic but also the runtime performance as you mentioned. However, I suppose that your rules can be optimized a lot so that the parameter would be an option again.

I hope this helps.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks for this answer, we're looking, how we can convert these tips into changes in out ruta-project. Actually, we're facing many amounts of arrays of arraylist in our heapdumps, some inefficient rules we're converted, but it still has memory peaks around 600m, so we're looking for another solution. One obvious case was the ticket we've created, but that is not the only one where big, empty arrays are generated.

The CASImpl class generates some heaps with solid sized, so that is another point to improve memory performance

Comment: You can of course also split the documents and process the parts separately/sequentially. But you probably know that, and this is often not an option.

Comment: Reducing the amount of RutaBasic annoations could be a good option for you. Do you really need the TokenSeed annotations?

Comment: We're looking for a solution because we have already an own Seeder, if there is a leak as well.

Splitting the document is quite an alternate but bad idea, because we would loose cross-over information between, so it's not recommended to do so. As we read at the mailing lists, there were some candidates with around 18Mb or 9Gb documents, so we want to be able to process that amount and therefore are looking to improve our rules and code.

Comment: Do you mean by leak a memory leak or a high memory consumption? There should be no memory leak in ruta, but a high consumption. Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: I don't know how I should describe it. We figured out some points that have been fixed, like thes inperformant rules, but there are still some points we don't know how to take care of them. Some are these initialized arrays with big size like StringHeap and ByteHeap, that are never filled up in our setup but are showing as empty positions in these arrays in our dumps, so they're wasting some memory. If these are the only bad guys is not be clear.

Comment: In addition we're taking care of our seeder-implementation and check it in regard of memory consumption because of the endless annotations been made.

Comment: We'd figured out, that there is a class named RuleElementMatch, that is increased rapidly, so we want to set up an exception, to cancel the further excecution of ruta, because the rule set has some memory issues. Do you know another entry point we could check in this case, which could be possible aside the RuleElementMatch or RutaRule's apply method, where an exception could be placed for such cases?

Comment: I do not know if I understand what you are suggesting. I would investigate the reason why the memory usage of RuleElementMatch is increased. If it is not the debug mode, then it is probably a problemtic rule with too many rule element matches, which should be easy to refactor. Are there any rule lement quantifiers? Do you maybe want to continue the problem finding on the UIMA user/dev mailing list?

Comment: You need to set the configuration parameter 'lowMemoryProfile' to true